# Python ctypes character pointer and string length issues

Tags: python, c++, ctypes

### The problem

I am trying to write an external library to be called from python, and want to use `ctypes` to pass information between python and C++. To do this, I define a global variable called `msg` in C++, and get my C++ code to write messages to this global variables. The idea is then that Python can read the messages when required. However, I seem to be running into constraints about the length of this message.

### Sample Code

Here is some code prototype that reproduces the problem.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

std::ostringstream msg;

void internal(){
    msg << " message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message  message ";
}

extern "C"{
    const char* external(){
        internal();
        return msg.str().c_str();
    }
}
```

`msg` is now a very long string. I save this in a file called `test.cpp` and compile this to a shared library:

```
g++ -c -fPIC test.cpp -o test.o
g++ -shared -Wl,-soname,test.so -o test.so test.o
```

I now open a python interpretor, and do the following

```
import ctypes
test = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary('test.so')
test.external.restype = ctypes.c_char_p

test.external()
```

The output is `''` instead of the super long string I constructed above.

I suppose that there is some sort of maximum to the length of the message that python will accept from the C++ program. However, in the use case that I have, the message may be of arbitrary length. How do I make sure that I am able to read the message into the python program?

If I replace the long string by a very short string, for instance

```
msg << " message ";
```

then everything works fine, and the python interpretor outputs `message`.

### System Information

Python interpretor

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux2
```

g++ compiler

```
g++ (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2
```

Comment: I am also wondering if valgrind might reveal something.

Comment: Nicely written question for a change. I will try to repro in a bit.  Can you binary search on message length to find minimum failing length? –

Comment: @JordanSamuels: If I replace the line that assigns `msg` in the `internal()` function by `for (int i = 0; i< 100; i++) msg << " message ";`, 100 seems to be the first length at which the python interpreter reliably produces the empty string as output.

Comment: I am seeing the same behavior - also, running through `valgrind` shows the usual python noise, plus some deletes of already freed memory from `std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::~basic_string()`.  I'm not sure if this is related; maybe one theory is that the code is flawed no matter what the length is, but at longer lengths it stomps over some other data, preventing the result from being visible/copied?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, the answer is so obvious I'm embarrassed I didn't see it at first.  The `str()` method is creating a temporary string, whose pointer is invalid after the string goes out of scope at the end of the `internal()` method.

The following code works:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

std::ostringstream msg;
std::string s;

void internal(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
      msg << " message ";
    }
    s = msg.str();
}
extern "C"{
    const char* external(){
        internal();
        return s.c_str();
    }
}
```

Comment: I find this surprising, though, because as long as the `std::ostringstream msg` object hasn't gone out of scope, I don't understand why pointers to it's internal contents should become invalid.

Comment: @CCG The str() method returns a copy - which is not part of the ostringstream's contents.